# The right way to convert Jni Type to Native type

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have the following function defined in my native library

```
JNIEXPORT jshortArray JNICALL
Java_net_example_android_library_audio_AudioFilter_process(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jshortArray readBuffer_) {
```

As you can see I am passing `jshortarray`

I have some native functions that accept `short*` as a parameter.

So I wonder, how can I convert `jshortarray` into a native one.

Is there any right way to do this ?

Or I should do something like that

```
int input_size = env->GetArrayLength(readBuffer_);
short input[input_size];
jshort *inputArray = env->GetShortArrayElements(readBuffer_, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < input_size; i++) {
    input[i] = inputArray[i];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `jshort *` is castable to `short *` Do the native functions expect the `short *` to be valid after they return? BTW—`GetShortArrayElements` should be followed by `ReleaseShortArrayElements`.

Comment: @TomBlodget thanks for the reply, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo012

You can find there sample where `jshort*` is used in code as `short*`. You can do that because of `typdef` statements inside `jni.h`:

```
typedef unsigned char   jboolean;
typedef unsigned short  jchar;
typedef short           jshort;
typedef float           jfloat;
typedef double          jdouble;
```

This way, you can simply use `jshort` as new name for `short`

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo012_PassArray_passShortArray
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jshortArray array) {
 
  /* get size of the array */
  jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);
 
  /* get the body of array; it will be referecende by C pointer */
  jshort *body = (*env)->GetShortArrayElements(env, array, 0);
 
  /* do some stuff */
  for(int i=0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("Short value: %hd\n", body[i]);
  }
  /* release body when you decide it is no longer needed */
  (*env)->ReleaseShortArrayElements(env, array, body, 0);
}
```

You can always double check how types are defined here: `jni.h` and `$PLATFORM/jni_md.h` inside JDK directory.

It's also good to keep this one handy:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

One remark! Note that arrays >= 2D are managed completely different way.